# Authenticate with a POST to a remote server - how to control PHP session?

Tags: php, session

I have two PHP servers.  Let's call them local server and remote server.

A user logs into a website on local server but when a link is clicked, data is to be retrieved from the remote server.

The remote server requires a login before the data can be accessed.  The login is done via POST.

I've been able to perform a POST from local server to remote server successfully and have received the successful login page.  However, when the necessary data is requested, the remote server acts as if there is no login session.

I suspect this is a problem with PHP session IDs not matching up.  My reason for thinking this is I think the remote server is obtaining the local server PHP session ID and not finding a match and therefore acts as there is not a valid login.

How can I keep the remote session alive to enable the data to be retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use one database & table for sessions. On the local server manage it (store & update) and when requesting data from remote pass a variable in the POST called session & check it with database.

Comment: Unfortunately the remote server is a closed product and I am unable to modify it.

Comment: Did you request the data by cURL? If so, you can store cookies from logging in by 2 parameters in the cURL and in the .txt file. Then you can try to obtain the data also with cookies (and then the session stored in cookie).

Comment: No, not using curl just PHP.  See example at http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm

Comment: Oh well, sorry, no experience in that one.

Comment: Even if I do get the session id from the remote server, what should I do with it?  I thought about setting the session id on local to match but this would then cause issues with the local login session.  I'm at a loss as to how to logically deal with this issue